# Install TortoiseSVN with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, installer

I am looking for a way to install TortoiseSVN via a batch file in order to automate the process of setting it up on several Windows machines.

Is it possible to do that maybe with the official installer, or even by using some 3rd party tool, with which i can just type in a command in a batch file, double click it and get it to install with no needed input from the user (and preferably with no GUI..) ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have group policy?

Comment: yes i believe so

Comment: you should be able to have your admin push it out with the msi.

Comment: cool, i have admin rights on the machines :) how exactly would i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like they provide a MSI installer which couldn't be easier to automate. Just run it with `/qn`, for more see the [Command-Line Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

So you can have a 1 line BAT file with the following:

`msiexec /i [msi file] /qn`

Comment: umm /qn didn't work, i tried /quiet it seems to be doing something but im not sure if it installed, ill try that again

Comment: @DanyKhalife that should have worked. I'm downloading the MSI now to see what's up.

Comment: yup i confirm that, i had svnserve running which prevented the uninstall/reinstall

Comment: thanks for your quick and precise input! very much appreciated :)

Comment: Not a problem :)