# Batch file to install TotalCommander without User intervention

Tags: batch-file

I am new to windows batch file. Here is my first attempt in batch file.
Here is my requirement:

I should have batch file. When executes, it should read the XML config file for the software list to be installed and the location of destination.

When I execute the batch script, it should install all the software mentioned in the XML config file, without user intervention.

All the software are `.exe` extension

For now, I have started with installing one software like below:

```
set tool=\\igdb001\didc0005\50_Tools\SW\TotalCommander\02_Installation
echo installing the tool commander 
start /w %tool%\tcm801x64.exe /silent
echo finished installing
```

It is prompting for user to choose the option during installation. How should automate it?

Comment: you need a setup that will allow silent install...... ".msi" files allow silent installs. Depends on the application, there might be a msi inside the compiled exe file.... try extracting exe with 7-zip

Answer (score 1):

Installing an MSI file can usually be done by tinkering with it with OCRA from Microsoft, or by tinkering with some switches and setup files.

You can quite often install programs with things like a custom setup.inf or a "response file", which is how the big lads do it.

For myself, I normally install the program through a series of zips and registry files.  I run many different operating systems, and the core install takes up a small directory that fits onto a diskette (save the programs).

`conset` by Frank Westlake, will read registry into the current environment.
`reg`  sets up the current environment in registry.  I use `HKCU\Software\Wendy` for this.  So programs are not set up to a directory like `L:\newin\myapp`, but the `L:\newin` is extracted from registry.

Most of the programs are already setup portable or semi-portable.  The registration is done by copying files into the windows directory, the windows system directory, etc, and registering the OCX's etc.  Batch files create the shortcuts, again, the locations are pulled from registry by conset.

To make life easier, i use the same registry settings in a `cdf` batch, which looks for the name (eg `cdf sendto` in the user, machine, and wendy files.  So i can cdf to the directory i keep my DOS exes in (cdf dosexe).

With just a switch (cdf /w), i can open the registry at that point (by using regjump).

Answer (score 0):

This is for a silent install of Total Commander:

EXTRACT your "tcm801x64.exe" file (with TC or 7-zip), and modify the "install.inf" file contained within the "tcm801x64.exe" file. Set the following:

> [auto]
>   auto=1

(0=interactive setup, 1=unattended setup)

Once you have modified the install.inf according to your needs and packed it back into the file tcm801x64.exe, you simply launch tcm801x64.exe and TC will install in unattended mode without asking the user any questions.

**EDIT:**

You can also create your own MSI instead of using a self extracting archive.
[Advance Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/top-freeware-features.html) has a free "simple" version that allows you to create window installer application (msi). Simple but easy and gives you a lot more control and power installing applications. Create the MSI and then you can use active directory to assign and install applications and not work with scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Logman. I do not want to modify the exe files since it is been widely used across Business units. I need to modify my batch file script such that it should install the exe tool with out prompting for user. I was just looking at msiexe command. not sure whether I can use this to install .exe. ( http://superuser.com/questions/602081/install-tortoisesvn-with-a-batch-file?rq=1). I tired executing this " msiexec /i \\igdb001\didc0005\50_Tools\SW\TotalCommander\02_Installation\tcm801x64.exe /qn " however it is not doing anything. it just returns to command prompt.

Comment: msiexec can open only .msi packages. And the only reason that "[auto]" is there, is for exactly what you want. You will not be able to install it silently without a msi or modifying the inf file.

Comment: Thanks Logman. I just tried setting auto=1 in install.inf file and executing exe file, it installs with out user intervention in the destination directory which is specified in install.inf file. my requirement here is, it should install in the desired location which I mention in batch file. Can I do this without modifying the destination directory in install.inf file. I did not understand "You will not be able to install it silently without a msi" What is this msi option. I know msi is microsoft installer, there would be file with .msi extension. how can i acheive my task with msi.

Comment: Ok. reading all your comments above clearly, I understood that the setup which ends with .msi extension, allow silent installtion otherwise it prompts user for interaction unless we set auto=1 in install.inf file. that is the reason we have 2 options 1. with msi 2.setting auto 1 in install.inf. this sounds good. I can talk to my manager and deal with option 2 by setting auto =1. how about changing the default destination directory.

Comment: I have one more question here.I have extracted the .exe using 7zip.however i want to pack it back the directory with .exe where by clicking on .exe file, should install the software. I tried with 7 Zip GUI to create a self-extracting archive. Choosing the SFX option when creating a 7z archive. this more or less work like unzipping the folder.

Comment: Use 7-Zip to Create Self Extracting executable, or you can create your own MSI file that can install silently with far greater control. A really nice msi creator and it's free is called Advanced Installer...... http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-simple.html

Comment: Thanks Logman for replying from time to time and bearing my questions. with option 1) 7zip Self Extracting executable,it works like unZipping when I click on newly created executable file.(http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLPdHgQzVxY) I need to pack the files into executable such that when I click on execuatable file, it should take me to installation window of software. 2)This script is being executable by many of the team members, i do not want create extra task on Users to install Advance installer and pack into msi file.